# How is Hanstone compared to other quartz products?

Tags: kitchen-counters, kitchens, stone

We're settled on putting in quartz countertops in our new kitchen, but now we're down to comparing and pricing various brand-name products.

I've looked at Cambria and a few others, but they are a bit pricey. We've found a company that sells and installs Hanstone, and the prices are very reasonable by comparison. The dealer said  the price difference was mostly due to cheaper transportation from Canada to Texas versus most quartz manufacturers being overseas.

Any opinions on Hanstone's product line as it compares to others? Anything about quartz in general that I need to be on the look-out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handstone is an engineered product, not a cut stone product. The parent company is not from Canada, rather Korea. (Hanwha L&C). Cut granite and quartz is commonly produced here in the northeast, especially in VT & NH. The average cost for real cut stone, polished, sealed and cut to order runs about $65/sq.ft.